# Amazing Android Drawable make a background like that?

Tags: android, png, drawable

Can Android Drawable make a background for different screensize like 'Figure 2' from a png file like 'Figure 1'?

```
       ..
       ..

   Figure 1 (four dot)




    ............
    ............
    ............
    ............
    ............
    ............

 Figure 2 ( a lot of dot)
```

Comment: Recommended reading http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
And also this one http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Answer (score 0):

you can use tilt mode for this

```
    <bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/i_b_top"
        android:tileMode="repeat"
        android:gravity="top">
    </bitmap>
```